# Single and Multi array

Tags: c++, arrays

multi choice Test how am i to send the correctcount variables to the array score[8]...
eg. the key was used to scan the array answers and got 7 the first line but now how do i update the 7 to the array score[0]. the program is working, i just need to know how the update the array score properly so i can find avg thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS = 8;
    const int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 10;
    int score[8];
    string studentnames[8];
    double avg;

    // Students' answers to the questions
    char answers[NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS][NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS] =
    { { 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
    { 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
    { 'E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
    { 'C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
    { 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
    { 'B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
    { 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' },
    { 'E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D' } };

    // Key to the questions
    char keys[] = { 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D' };

    //Loop for student
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Student #" << i + 1 << " Name: ";
        cin >> studentnames[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; i++)
    {
        // Grade one student
        int correctCount = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; j++)
        {
            if(answers[i][j] == keys[j])
                correctCount++;
        }
        //output Student name and test Score 
        cout << "Student Name is : " << studentnames[i] << endl;
        cout << "Score of the test is " << correctCount << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: instead of incrementing correctCount you could increment score[i]  or just assign `score[i]=correctCount;`

Comment: i already tried that when i try to  get the avg it gives a negative number ... i dont think i want to change the correctcount but update the answer array into the score array

Comment: Why not change `char answers` to `std::vector<std::string>`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `score` as `double`, or do a float calculation and multiply the score by 100

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; i++)
{
    // Grade one student
    int correctCount = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; j++)
    {
        if(answers[i][j] == keys[j])
            correctCount++;
    }
    score[i] = 100 * ((double)correctCount / (double)NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS);

    cout 
        << "Name: " << studentnames[i] 
        << ", correctCount: " << correctCount 
        << ", average: " << score[i] << "\n";
}
```

Not related to your question, but you can make your code easier to debug by declaring the names of the students as well, instead of taking input every time. You can comment out user input section later.

```
//for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
//{
//  cout << "Enter Student #" << i + 1 << " Name: ";
//  cin >> studentnames[i];
//}
std::string studentnames[NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS] =
{ "n1","n2","n3","n4","n5","n6","n7","n8" };
```